# Create View Model using MVVMCross built in factory?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a situation where I want to "resolve" view models without having to manually call out to the IoC container to resolve a viewmodels dependencies.

I'm assuming that internally Mvvmcross has a viewmodel factory used to create viewmodels while injecting their dependencies.

Can I call into that directly? If so, what is it called and what namespaces do these factories reside in?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a "HomeViewModel" for a tabcontroller but don't want to hardcode the dependency resolution for each "tabs" view model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I personally do is to use IoC in my `HomeViewModel` to get the all the dependencies of the nested `ViewModel`s and pass them along when I instantiate them. So something in the likes of:

```
private ITwitterService _twitterService;
private IFacebookService _facebookService;
private IDataProcessingService _dataProcessingService;
private TwitterViewModel _twitterViewModel;
private FacebookViewModel _facebookViewModel;

public HomeViewModel(ITwitterService t, IFacebookService f, IDataProcessingService d)
{
    _twitterService = t;
    _facebookService = f;
    _dataProcessingService = d;
    _twitterViewModel = new TwitterViewModel(_twitterService, _dataProcessingService);
    _facebookViewModel = new FacebookViewModel(_facebookService, _dataProcessingService);
}
```

Then I simply use those instances of my `ViewModel`s in my tabs.

Comment: +1 - that's what the stuff i build does too. i guess you can also use `Mvx.IocConstruct` if you want to, or if you want full navigation-parameter-type-creation you can try to `Mvx.Resolve` the `IMvxViewModelLoader` too

Comment: This is what I was originally thinking about doing but wasn't sure if there was a more correct way. Works for me +1

Comment: Yeah OK it works .. But then you are pushing the dependencies of your sub view models up to the parent ... Totally defeats the purpose of IOC as far as "Separation of Concerns" .. Not that I have a better answer .. but I feel there should be one.